# Optimization Problems

Tags: calculus

the sum of three non-negative numbers is 39/5 and one of them is the square of another. What must those three numbers be for your product to be maximum?

Comment: What have you tried?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: Like $x+x^2+y=\frac{39}{5}$ and $x^3y\to\max$? Are Lagrange multipliers allowed?

Answer (score 4):

We have a relation
$$x+x^2+y = 39/5$$
We want to find
$$\max(x\cdot x^2 \cdot y)= \max(x^3y)$$

Now we can use our relation to simplify the expression we want to maximize. We can rewrite the relation into:

$$y=39/5-x-x^2$$

And multiply together:

$$\max(x^3(39/5-x-x^2))$$

Now maybe you can take it from here?